# Array of Objects Mapping Not Valid React

Tags: reactjs, mapping

In my component's render function, I am trying to map an array of objects. I keep receiving the error "Objects are not valid as a React child". However, I am not trying to render the object. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Note: circlesarray is an array (filled with Objects)

```
return (
  <Container>
    <NavBar>
      <Subtitle>All</Subtitle>
      <Subtitle>Living groups</Subtitle>
      <Subtitle>Clubs</Subtitle>
      <Subtitle>Classes</Subtitle>
    </NavBar>
    <CircleBox>
      {circlesarray.map((circle, index) => (
        <Circle key={index} name={circle.name} />
      ))}
    </CircleBox>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: UPDATE: I tried removing everything inside of return except for Container tag and a Text tag, and the error is still happening!

Comment: Can you add the Container component code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the folowing:

```
  {circlesarray.map((circle, index) => 
    <Circle key={index} name={circle.name} />
  )}
```

Without the ().

Comment: So I originally tried that, but then VS Code automatically adds the () back...